# setTimeout not the same as this.async?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Sometimes I'm coding in a wrong way my polymer 1.0 web app and stuff stops to work properly. Like setting data to some custom element and then immediately trying to read some data out of it (that depends on the data just set) (because I don't know better). Sometimes this doesn't work. Most of the time `this.async` will help me out, but sometimes it will not. However, `setTimeout` has never ever failed me in these kind of situations. Most of the time calling `setTimeout` without providing wait time will work just as well.

For a long time I thought that `this.async(function(){...})` is the same as `setTimeout(function(){...})`. Because sometimes code inside `this.async` will fail to see changes in custom element's data while code inside `setTimeout` will not.

Are these two methods are implemented in different way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`this.async` adds your function to the start of the event queue, while `setTimeout` adds it to the end. If you use `setTimeout` other functions may have been executed before your function is called, causing the changes that you can see in your data.

From the [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html) of `this.async`:

> If no wait time is specified, runs tasks with microtask timing (after the current method finishes, but **before the next event from the event queue is processed**)

setTimeout on the other hand will add your function to the end of the queue as is described in the section "Adding Messages" of this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

> Calling `setTimeout` will add a message to the queue after the time passed as second argument. If there is no other message in the queue, the message is processed right away; however, if there are messages, the setTimeout message **will have to wait for other messages to be processed**. For that reason the second argument indicates a minimum time and not a guaranteed time